# Generics wildcard parameter lower bound to Object

Tags: java, generics, wildcard

It is possible to specify a wildcard type that has a *lower* bound to `Object`:

```
public void method(Collection<? super Object> c) {
    // compiles, but ? can only be Object
}
```

Logically the unknown type can only be `Object` (no type is *above* `Object` in the class hierarchy).

Is there ever a requirement or good reason to use a type of `<? super Object>`?

Comment: Hunting for hats, are you? :-)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14106899/generic-lower-bound-to-object

Comment: @Jan You bet :) It's actually hard to come up with original question content. There are so many questions already out there

Comment: @ShivamKalra This is a different question. The other one had syntax issues...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes, there is a use case for "? super XXXXXX", as outlines [here](http://www.javabeat.net/2008/09/using-super-in-generics-java-5-0/). the gist is the using user/extends will make your collection either read only or write only.

Comment: The question us mot a general one about extends XXXX, but specifically about ? extends Object

Comment: oh. so no, there's no use for "? extends Object" except to stop annoying IDE warnings about a collection not being generic.